# New application, running rspec gives allot of warnings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a pretty much new rails 4.1.1 project setup, I added rspec and ran the generator etc.

I have added 1 controller and maybe 2 models so far.

My gemfile.lock has this:

```
 rspec-core (3.0.2)
      rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.0.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.0.2)
      rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
    rspec-rails (3.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.0.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.0.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.0.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
    rspec-support (3.0.2)
```

Now when I run rspec I get this output:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/version.rb:5: warning: loading in progress, circular require considered harmful - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass.rb
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in  `<main>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in  `eval'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/bin/rspec:23:in  `<main>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/bin/rspec:23:in  `load'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/exe/rspec:4:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in  `invoke'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in  `run'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in  `run'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in  `setup'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in  `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in  `each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in  `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in  `load'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb:1:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/config/environment.rb:2:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/config/environment.rb:2:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/config/application.rb:14:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:131:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in  `each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in  `block in require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in  `each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in  `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:1:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb:1:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass.rb:9:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass.rb:9:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/version.rb:5:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/version.rb:5:in  `require'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/version.rb:115: warning: File.exists? is a deprecated name, use File.exist? instead
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/version.rb:90: warning: File.exists? is a deprecated name, use File.exist? instead
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/version.rb:95: warning: File.exists? is a deprecated name, use File.exist? instead
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/node.rb:73: warning: method redefined; discarding old children=
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:197: warning: literal in condition
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb:8: warning: loading in progress, circular require considered harmful - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/string.rb
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in  `<main>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in  `eval'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/bin/rspec:23:in  `<main>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/bin/rspec:23:in  `load'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/exe/rspec:4:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in  `invoke'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in  `run'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in  `run'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in  `setup'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in  `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in  `each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in  `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in  `load'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb:1:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/config/environment.rb:2:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/config/environment.rb:2:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/config/application.rb:14:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:131:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in  `each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in  `block in require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in  `each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in  `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:1:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb:1:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass.rb:93:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass.rb:93:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:40:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:40:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script.rb:4:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script.rb:4:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/operation.rb:2:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/operation.rb:2:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/string.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/string.rb:1:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb:7:in  `<module:Script>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb:8:in  `<class:Literal>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb:8:in  `require'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/number.rb:1: warning: loading in progress, circular require considered harmful - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in  `<main>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in  `eval'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/bin/rspec:23:in  `<main>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/bin/rspec:23:in  `load'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/exe/rspec:4:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in  `invoke'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in  `run'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in  `run'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in  `setup'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in  `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in  `each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in  `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in  `load'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb:1:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/config/environment.rb:2:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/config/environment.rb:2:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/config/application.rb:14:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:131:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in  `each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in  `block in require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in  `each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in  `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:1:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb:1:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass.rb:93:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass.rb:93:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:40:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:40:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script.rb:4:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script.rb:4:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/operation.rb:2:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/operation.rb:2:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/string.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/string.rb:1:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb:7:in  `<module:Script>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb:9:in  `<class:Literal>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb:9:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/number.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/number.rb:1:in  `require'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/color.rb:1: warning: loading in progress, circular require considered harmful - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in  `<main>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in  `eval'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/bin/rspec:23:in  `<main>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/bin/rspec:23:in  `load'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/exe/rspec:4:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in  `invoke'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in  `run'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in  `run'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in  `setup'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in  `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in  `each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in  `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in  `load'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb:1:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/config/environment.rb:2:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/config/environment.rb:2:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/dev/gitserver/testapp1/testapp1/config/application.rb:14:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:131:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in  `each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in  `block in require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in  `each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in  `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:1:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb:1:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass.rb:93:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass.rb:93:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:40:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:40:in  `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@testapp1/gems/sass-
```

...

What is the problem, is rails 4.1.1 not compatible with rspec yet?

Answer (score 5):

Just remove the `--warning` option from your `/.rspec` file, as it is now a default.

Comment: hmm..that's a strange fix :)  How can I fix the problem though?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. What I meant was that you became aware of these warnings because the `--warning` became a default, not because of an incompatibility with Rails. Also, I just found out that it has been fixed in rspec-core: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/commit/c51d38ccdd39adcc8f5554c9324421e7be89d9b7

Answer (score 0):

I specified `warning = false` in my `Rakefile`:

```
Rake::TestTask.new(:concepts) do |t|
  #...
  t.warning = false
end
```